# Combine nested columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [4,5,6]})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['hello','world'], axis=1)
df[('hello','new_col')] = df[('world','data')]*2
print (df)
  hello world   hello
   data  data new_col
0     1     4       8
1     2     5      10
2     3     6      12
```

When I add a new nested column as above, it separates it from the existing `hello` column. How do I add a new nested column such that `new_col` is associated/beneath with the existing `hello` column? Can this be done during assignment or only after? I.e. I want the below

```
    hello        world
   data  new_col  data 
0     1     4       8
1     2     5      10
2     3     6      12
```

Comment: Just do `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this after:

```
df = df[['hello', 'world']]
print(df)

  hello         world
   data new_col  data
0     1       8     4
1     2      10     5
2     3      12     6
```